# Why is my makefile not compiling a java interface?

Tags: java, makefile, javac

I have a makefile to compile several .java files. It seems to locate the files just fine. However, when it attempts to compile the first java file it says that it cannot find symbol for State. State is an interface, and the only interface in my project.

```
javac src/hw4/ClosedState.java
src/hw4/ClosedState.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class ClosedState implements State {
                                    ^
  symbol: class State
src/hw4/ClosedState.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    public void doAction(Context context) { context.setState(this); }
                         ^
  symbol:   class Context
  location: class ClosedState
src/hw4/ClosedState.java:5: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
3 errors
```

This is my makefile:

```
JAVAC=javac
sources = $(shell find ./src/hw4/ -type f -name '*.java')
classes = $(sources:.java=.class)

all: myProgram jar clean

myProgram: $(classes)

clean :
        rm -f *.class

%.class : %.java
        $(JAVAC) $<

jar: $(classes)
        jar cvf dl.jar $(classes)
```

'hw4' is the package name and I am running the makefile from outside the src directory.

Answer (score 0):

Got it using the -cp option:

```
-cp ./src
```